# Radiobutton in Tkinter calling function

Tags: python, button, tkinter, radio-button, invoke

I have code for radio buttons in tkinter. I am struggling to write the code that invokes the button command. Basically I want the user to be able to choose a time frame and a person. I have three different files that run three different data analyses, so I want the three files to run but only take data from the time frame and for that person.

```
from Tkinter import *

class RBDemo:
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.v = IntVar()

        #Put the first group of radio buttons in their own frame.
        f1 = Frame(win, borderwidth=3, relief=RAISED)
        rb1 = Radiobutton(f1, text="This Week", variable=self.v, value=1)
        rb2 = Radiobutton(f1, text="This Month", variable=self.v, value=2)
        rb3 = Radiobutton(f1, text="This Year", variable=self.v, value=3)
        rb1.pack(anchor=W);  rb2.pack(anchor=W);   rb3.pack(anchor=W)
        f1.pack(side=LEFT)

        #Button one will be selected by default
        self.v.set(1)


        #Make a second group of radiobuttons in their own frame.
        #Make first button the default
        self.v2 = StringVar()
        f2 = Frame(win, borderwidth=2, relief=SOLID)

        rb4 = Radiobutton(f2, text="Bob", variable=self.v2, value="Bob")
        rb5 = Radiobutton(f2, text="Stacy", variable=self.v2, value="Stacy")
        rb6 = Radiobutton(f2, text="Both", variable=self.v2, value="Both") 
        rb4.pack(anchor=W);  rb5.pack(anchor=W); rb6.pack(anchor=W)
        f2.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.v2.set("Bob")

        #Make a button that prints what each value is when clicked
        b = Button(win, text="Let's do this!", command=self.clicked)
        b.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)


    def clicked(self):
        print("button clicked!")
        print("v is:", self.v.get())
        print("v2 is:", self.v2.get() )




mw = Tk()
app = RBDemo(mw)
mw.mainloop()
```

I tried

```
    def selected(self):
    if self.my_var.get()==1:
        "do something"
        elif self.my_var.get()==2:
            "do something"
            else:
                "do something"
```

but this doesn't seem to work, nor is it very pythonic considering I have to run three files using the input from the button.

Comment: A short `if..elif..else` block is perfectly Pythonic (when properly indented).

Comment: The indentation of your code is incorrect.

Comment: You should also replace the self.my_var with self.v ...

Answer (score 1):

First, When properly indented, an if - elif block is perfectly ok. So you could just use

```
if whatevervar.get() == 1:
    dosomethingfancy()
elif whatevervar.get() == 2:
    dosomethingcool()
#and so on
```

In other languages there is something like a switch - case block: [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_case) There is no such construct in Python, but there is a neat little trick that helps especially when dealing with bigger code blocks:

```
Options = {
         1: dosomething,
         2: dosomethingelse
}

#execution
Options[myvar.get()]()
```

Basically, a dictionary is defined, that maps its key values to functions. Mind the parentheses: You don't want to call the function, when the dictionary is defined.

Comment: I feel silly for the improper indents. Thanks. If I use a forloop, and there are 9 combinations of buttons, will I have nine different elif sections? if self.v.get() == 1 & self.v.get() == Bob, elif self-v-get() == 1 & self.v.get()==Stacy, etc?